# Circular View Path error on applying @ResponseBody

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have the below Controller.

```
@Controller
public class AppController {

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    @ResponseBody
    public User home() {
        User u = new User();
        u.setUserId(10);
        u.setUserName("Rahul");
        return u;
    }
}
```

when I comment out the annotation @ResponseBody I get an error while calling /home url.Why?
The message is below

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [home]: would
>   dispatch back to the current handler URL [/home] again. Check your
>   ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified
>   view, due to default view name generation.)   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.prepareForRendering(InternalResourceView.java:209)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:147)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1370)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1116)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645)
>   ~[javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEAS

But when I change my controller method to the below I don't get any error :-
Why?

```
 @RequestMapping("/home")
//@ResponseBody // commented
 public ResponseEntity<User>  home(){

      User u = new User();
      u.setUserId(10);
      u.setUserName("Raj");

  return ResponseEntity.ok(u);  

}
```

Comment: Because of the rules detailed here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-return-types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Controller will not work stand-alone without @ResponseBody or ResponseEntity

ResponseEntity is like @ResponseBody but with status and headers.

Why we need @ResponseBody ?

Because, if any of your request mapping method, like home(), contains @ResponseBody annotation it gives an indication that a method return value should be bound to the web response body and if we don’t mention @ResponseBody, then the returned Object will be considered as one of the View and ViewResolver will start looking for respective view in the application.

For further details please refer: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-return-types